# Shortcut active when modal dialog is active

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I have a QML application with two menu item:

- *File/Open...* trigger open file modal dialog
- *Control/Up* just log something on the output console. This item has the up arrow keyboard shortcut association.

Strangely, the shortcut is still active when the open file dialog is display. This make impossible the use of the up arrow to select a given file for example since the shortcut is bind to another action.

In a regular *Qt* widget application, the menu shortcut is not handled when a modal dialog is on screen.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Qt.labs.platform 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
    }

    MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Open")
                shortcut: StandardKey.Open
                onTriggered: fileDialog.open()
            }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("Control")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Up")
                shortcut: "Up"
                onTriggered: console.log("up!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using *Qt 5.12.3* on *macOS 10.14.4*.

Comment: In Linux works correctly since the FileDialog gets the focus, it is probably a bug only Mac OS so I recommend you report a bug.

Comment: Done here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75487

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, so this is a shot in the dark. Have you tried forcing focus onto `FileDialog`?

```
FileDialog {
   id: fileDialog
   Item {
     id: focus
   }
   onVisibleChanged: if(visible) focus.forceActiveFocus()
}
```

This will force the focus on the `FileDialog` as a parent of `focus`.

Comment: if the above doesn't work, try `shortcut: fileDialog.visible? "" : "Up"`

Comment: Unfortunately, the first workaround doesn't work... It would have been simpler because the second force me to use it on each *MenuItem* shortcut property.

Comment: @MartinDelille If you create your own `MenuItem` module and bind the visibility of the dialog to a property that, when set, automatically sets your `shortcut` to empty. That way, you won't have to do it manually for each one.